# "Mining your life is the only way to stumble on anything real"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I came across this sentence by actor Ethan Hawk in a newspaper.I know what "to mine" means and I took it as figuratively as well but still  I am stumped.What could it mean?

Comment: So what does *mine* mean? What difficulty do you have applying it to 'your life'?

Comment: What @CarSmack said. To *mine one's life* has no currency as a special idiom, and native speakers are no better equipped than learners to extrapolate the intended figurative sense in this context. So I think it's General Reference.

Comment: There's a somewhat related statement by [Socrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) often quoted as "the unexamined life is not worth living".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging down into yourself, examining yourself, to find something new, deeper, forgotten, more honest.

As an actor, he might mean to find something realistic to portray in a character requires looking within to find an authentic related experience. Or if he's talking about a general life philosophy, he probably got it from a set of ideas that many actors use.